# Aria2c multiple video download

Tags: linux, arch-linux, manjaro, aria2

I want to install multiple videos without waiting for each video installation to complete and type the link to the other video and doing the same thing again.

let's say i have 5 videos to be downloaded,  can someone suggest a method so that i can install them one after the other without doing it manually using aria2?

Answer (score 1):

Run 5 instances of `aria2` in background and they will be downloaded simultaneously.

```
nohup aria2 URL1... &
nohup aria2 URL2... &
nohup aria2 URL3... &
nohup aria2 URL4... &
nohup aria2 URL5... &
```

If you have URLs in file you can try something like to download them consecutively:

```
while read i;
do
aria2 "$i"
done <file_with_urls
```

**And you do not install video**!!! Video is a file and you download/copy/move it.